# Занести массив данных в БД Yii2

Tags: php, sql, yii2

Ломаю голову, не могу придумать как реализовать

Есть форма, в ней multi select (выбор сразу нескольких значений)

View на создание клиента

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Выберите менеджера:</label>
            
            <select class="select2 mb-3 select2-multiple select2-hidden-accessible" style="width: 100%" multiple="" data-placeholder="Выерите 1 или нескольких" name="responsible_manager[]" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
                <option value="">Не привязывать</option>
                                        <option value="3">manager1@mail.ru</option>      
                                        <option value="5">manager2@ya.ru</option>      
                                        <option value="7">manager3@mail.ru</option>      
                                        <option value="28">manager4</option>      
                                        <option value="30">manager15</option>      
                                        <option value="34">manager13</option>      
                                        <option value="35">manager156</option>      
                                </select><span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default select2-container--focus select2-container--below" dir="ltr" style="width: 100%;"><span class="selection"><span class="select2-selection select2-selection--multiple" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="-1"><ul class="select2-selection__rendered"><li class="select2-search select2-search--inline"><input class="select2-search__field" type="search" tabindex="0" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="none" spellcheck="false" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" placeholder="Выерите 1 или нескольких" style="width: 1350.25px;"></li></ul></span></span><span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>

        <div class="help-block"></div>
    </div>
```

Далее, по нажатию кнопки отправляю в контроллер.
В контроллере получаю массив (всех менеджеров которых выбрал во view) при вызове post запроса

```
var_dump($this->request->post('responsible_manager'));
```

Получается при вардампе получаю все id менеджеров которых выбрал

array(3) {
[0]=>
string(1) "7"
[1]=>
string(2) "28"
[2]=>
string(2) "34"
}

**Задача**

В БД есть отдельная таблица `table_links` в ней столбец `id_manager`.
Как все данные в массиве которые я получил внести в эту таблицу?

По сути должна создаться новая запись для каждого менеджера в одну колонку и в эту запись записаться id менеджера в колонку `id_manager`

Пробовал через `foreach` играться и `while` цикл использовать (чтобы считать кол-во в массиве и повторить запись на загрузку в БД с другим id массива).
Но это работает если в БД уже есть такая запись и это актуально для редактировании.
А так всегда прилетает либо одна последняя запись или ничего

Это нужно для того чтобы при создании карточки клиента, можно было выбрать нескольких менеджеров которые будут с ним работать и привязать их к этому же клиенту

Comment: https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/whatever/batch+insert+in+yii2

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У себя реализовал это так (в контреллере)

```
foreach ($this->request->post('responsible_manager') as $responsible_manager_post)
        {
            Yii::$app->db->createCommand()->batchInsert('table_links', ['id_manager'],[
                [$responsible_manager_post],
            ])->execute();
        }
```